# I do not get an output from JOptionPane

Tags: java

I have a little problem with my first JOptionPane program. I don't get my if-statements to output anything. What did I do wrong?

```
package test1;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Lol1 {
  public void test() {
    String res;
    res = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Does this work?");
    if (res == "Yes") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Good."); 
    }
    if (res == "No") {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You're lying."); 
        }
}



public static void main(String[] args) {
    Lol1 l1 = new Lol1();
    l1.test();
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem is that you have to use the equals method, not ==.

Comment: Isn't '==' to test equality and '=' assign? If i use '=' I get more problems.

Comment: Programming is about paying attention to details, like A) I wrote about **equals** method, not about assignment operator (=) B) Your question already got an "already answered" link up there. Digest that information first before coming up with the next question please.

Comment: You're right. Thank you. I learned a lot from the answers you submitted. It feels like I got screwed over by the paper I got from my professor.